# multiplying a 6 digit number by a randomly generated 4 digit number returns a long repeating string. [Python]

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to get a 6 digit number from the input (**THAT** works), then is multiplies that number by a random number between 1111 and 9999, records that number to the dictionary ('key'), and adds the result to the dictionary ('data'). I then make it print the dictionary, and it returns a string of repeating data.

#### example:

`input() = 123456`
`key = 1432`
result = 123456123456123456123456...

#### Here's my code:

```py
import random as r
chunk = {}
ipt = input()
int(ipt)
ky = r.randint(1111, 9999)
ipt *= ky
chunk['data'] = ipt
chunk['key'] = ky
print(chunk)
chunk.pop('data')
chunk.pop('key')
```

Comment: You don't assign result of `int(ipt)` to anything. Change it to `ipt = int(ipt)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrej points out in a comment, int() does not modify the variable passed to it.  It simply computes an answer and returns it.

Change

```
int(ipt)
```

to

```
ipt=int(ipt)
```

Comment: Or `ipt = int(input())`